# app crash when try to combine mp4 videos

Tags: android, video, mp4parser

I download the latest source code for mp4parser and use this to combine two mp4 files.
When I try to combine two mp4 videos app crashed.

when I run this line of code

```
  MovieCreator.build("mnt/sdcard/CamVideo/0.mp4")
```

The app crashed with and crash log is

```
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:             length=0; index=0
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.samples.DefaultMp4SampleList.<init>(DefaultMp4SampleList.java:52)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.mdat.SampleList.<init>(SampleList.java:33)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.Mp4TrackImpl.<init>(Mp4TrackImpl.java:59)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator.build(MovieCreator.java:58)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator.build(MovieCreator.java:39)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at com.coderzheaven.pack.CustomCameraActivity.MergeVideos(CustomCameraActivity.java:200)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at com.coderzheaven.pack.CustomCameraActivity$1.onClick(CustomCameraActivity.java:108)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4274)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17357)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
  08-11 17:27:49.023: E/AndroidRuntime(24864):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using the same properties files that is in sample code "isoparser-custom.properties" and "isoparser-default.properties"

I am expecting movie object should build  properly. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in this or can send me fully function code that merge two mp4 files.

**EDITED:**
I download this file "isoparser-1.0.2.jar" from maven project (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/mp4parser/isoparser/1.0.2/) and but app crashed with this crash report

```
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.coremedia.iso.PropertyBoxParserImpl.createBox(PropertyBoxParserImpl.java:86)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.coremedia.iso.AbstractBoxParser.parseBox(AbstractBoxParser.java:102)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.googlecode.mp4parser.BasicContainer.next(BasicContainer.java:155)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.googlecode.mp4parser.BasicContainer.hasNext(BasicContainer.java:131)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.googlecode.mp4parser.util.LazyList$1.hasNext(LazyList.java:55)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile.getMovieBox(IsoFile.java:109)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator.build(MovieCreator.java:48)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator.build(MovieCreator.java:35)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.coderzheaven.pack.CustomCameraActivity.MergeVideos(CustomCameraActivity.java:200)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.coderzheaven.pack.CustomCameraActivity$1.onClick(CustomCameraActivity.java:108)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.Factory
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.FileTypeBox.ajc$preClinit(FileTypeBox.java:1)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.FileTypeBox.<clinit>(FileTypeBox.java:1)
  08-18 17:32:20.571: E/AndroidRuntime(31446):  ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have not invoked the aspectJ compiler/compile time weaving when you were building the mp4parser on your own. Please either use a precompiled version - they are available on [maven central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/mp4parser/isoparser/) - or make sure that you invoke the compile time weaving.

Newer version than on Maven Central are available in [Sonatype OSS staging repositories](https://oss.sonatype.org/#view-repositories). In the header of the repository tab please select "Nexus Managed Repositories" (instead of User Managed Repositories) and search for mp4parser.

If you do not use a dependency management tool such as maven or gradle please also make sure that you include the [AspectJ runtime jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.0/aspectjrt-1.8.0.jar) (at the moment version 1.8.0).

Grüße,
Sebastian

Comment: Please see the edited question about my finding on your answer.

Comment: If there is any sample compile able project that merge two videos then please tell me about this.

Comment: added explanation of aspectJ dependency

Comment: Now it is working and I am able to merge two videos now. Thanks @Sebastian

Comment: I have added AspectJ and worked for me too, Thanks a lot. But if I dont add the Module Independence I get error.

Comment: @SebastianAnnies i am using eclipse and i have downloaded aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar and isoparser-1.1.2.jar. i hava added them to my projects build path (i am developing android app), i get null pointer exception when i am trying to use this line: Movie firstClip = MovieCreator.build("/sdcard/mvideo.mpg"); please help me to understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: I'm not going to debug your software in the comments here. But one thing I can see immediately is that the file extension doesn't seem to be a MP4. If you need more help please ask a proper question and include a stacktrace.